# Can you change google calendar user settings via API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to change user settings in google calendar via API? What I found on their developer web [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/settings) suggests that no, but maybe there is something I missed.

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google calendar api gives you access to a users google calendars.  It does not give you access to change any settings for the user on the Google calendar web application thats two different things.

You can update the calendar itself changing  [calendar update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/update) some of the basic information about a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately what you want cannot be achieved.**

As you clearly noticed in the [Calendar API documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/settings), the operations accepted for Calendar settings are: **get**, **list** and **watch**.

What you can do instead is to file a feature on request on Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=823906).